# c++ console buffer offset

Tags: c++, winapi

trying to write console using WINAPI WriteConsole function i found that console buffer seems to have some offset, but I can't get where to find it.

Here is the code sample where I change window and buffer sizes.

```
output_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SMALL_RECT window_size = { 0, 0, screen_size.X - 1, screen_size.Y - 1 };
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(output_handle, screen_size);
SetConsoleWindowInfo(output_handle, TRUE, &window_size);
```

After that I use next to fill wstring that should be passed to WriteConsole

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    screen_to_draw[i] = '!'; // it should be the first line
    screen_to_draw[screen_size.Y*screen_size.X - screen_size.X + i] = '!'; //and this one - the last one
}
```

And at the end:

```
WriteConsole(output_handle, screen_to_draw.c_str(), screen_size.X*screen_size.Y, done, NULL);
```

But using the code above i can't see the first line at all, and the last one placed the second from bottom.

If I modify code to next:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    screen_to_draw[screen_size.X+i] = '!'; // it should be the second line
}
```

This line will be the first at screen. So it seems that the first line of this buffer is over the screen, and the last one is in one line above the console's bottom.

There is no any other actions performed. 
Could you please assist with this case?

UPD:
Found the problem, after using WriteConsole function cursor moved to position next to data, and it's placed at the next line. That's why buffer moved up on one line.

Comment: You should switch `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` and `SetConsoleWindowInfo`. You cannot make the buffer smaller than the window. Also check the return values of each

Comment: In this case buffer is bigger than window

Comment: Found the problem, after using WriteConsole function cursor moved to position next to data, and it's placed at the next line. That's why buffer moved up on one line.